# C# I want to save the snapshot of the RDP screen in the background using MSTSCLib

Tags: c#, rdp

I'm working on a project to run multiple MSTSCLib RDP connections in the background. I need to save screenshots of each RDP connection after the connection is established. I want to collect these images in a folder without showing this to the user. I have the code below, but I can only get a black picture. How can I solve this problem?

```
public class RemoteDesktopApi
{
    private Thread _thread;

    public void connect(string _Ip, Int32 _Port, Int32 _witdh, Int32 _height, Int32 _timeout, string _User, string _Pass)
    {
        try
        {
            var rdpForm = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
            var rdp = new AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient6NotSafeForScripting();
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TaskScheduler>();
            
            rdp.Height = _height;
            rdp.Height = _height;
            rdp.Width = _witdh;
            rdpForm.Width = _witdh;
            rdpForm.Height = _height;
            rdpForm.Controls.Add(rdp);
            rdpForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            
            rdpForm.Show();
            
            rdpForm.Text = Convert.ToString(rdpForm.Handle);

            rdp.AdvancedSettings7.EnableWindowsKey = 1;
            rdp.AdvancedSettings7.DisableCtrlAltDel = 1;
            rdp.AdvancedSettings7.allowBackgroundInput = 1;
            rdp.AdvancedSettings7.AcceleratorPassthrough = 1;
            rdp.AdvancedSettings7.BitmapPeristence = 1;
            rdp.AdvancedSettings7.Compress = 1;
            rdp.AdvancedSettings7.DoubleClickDetect = 1;
            rdp.AdvancedSettings7.PerformanceFlags = 0x10;
            // rdpForm.ControlBox = false;
            //rdpForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

             rdpForm.Left = -2000;
            //rdpForm.MinimizeBox
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(rdpForm.Handle));

            rdp.Server = _Ip;
            rdp.UserName =_User;
            rdp.AdvancedSettings7.ClearTextPassword = _Pass;

            rdp.Connect();

            _thread = new Thread(startArg =>
            {
                while (rdp.Connected.ToString() == "2")
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }

                Thread.Sleep(5000);
              
                Control ctl = rdp;
                Control originalParent = ctl.Parent;
                int oldLeft = ctl.Left;
                ctl.Left = 22222;  // way outside
                ctl.Parent = rdpForm;
                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat fmt = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg;

                if ("test.png".ToLower().EndsWith(".png"))  
                    fmt = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png;

                using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ctl.ClientSize.Width, ctl.ClientSize.Height))
                {
                    ctl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, ctl.ClientRectangle);
                    bmp.Save("test.png", fmt);
                }

                ctl.Parent = originalParent;
                ctl.Left = oldLeft;
            
                rdpForm.Parent = originalParent;
                rdpForm.Left = oldLeft;

                rdp.Disconnect();

                rdpForm.Close();
            });

            _thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            _thread.IsBackground = true;
            _thread.Start();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: RDP uses it's own fake display driver and window resources. This means the application-level CPU on your system doesn't actually know what's on the screen for an RDP connection. You have to get into the driver/kernel module level stuff to see this, and the only way to do that is by asking the RDP display driver what it's drawing to the GPU. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do that, either.

Comment: How to steal login credentials is demonstrated in [this github project](https://github.com/zer0-t/RDP-screenshotter).  Hehe.

Comment: I studied them but I couldn't find a solution, unfortunately